# Is there a way to reverse this python function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

```
def function(value):
    bit = value << 1 
    movebit = bit & 255 
    if (value> 127 ):
        movebit = movebit | 1
    return (movebit)
```

I have got this piece of code that I am trying to reverse so for example
I know that the first line is actually to multiply the user_input and save it in bit.

the thing is I can not figure out how to change the next few lines to reverse the output.

example:

```
test = [226, 3, 214, 111, 20, 240]
# after function => [197, 6, 173, 222, 40, 225]
# goal is to reverse them back to test
toReverse = [197, 6, 173, 222, 40, 225]
```

my goal is to for loop over toReverse and on each element, send it to the function
and get back the number that is on the same index as testArray.

Comment: And how are user going to input numbers? Any specific format?

Comment: it is part of a bigger decryption task, so the numbers are not really inputted by a user, thanks for commenting, will update the question to make it clear.

Comment: The function uses `&` and `|` bitwise operations. These operations cannot be reversed.

Comment: I do know that those bitwise operations are not reversible but I thought maybe because of some of the variables are constant so for example on the line that includes ( movebit | 1) I understood that it basically the logic is same as movebit % 2 == 0 than it adds a 1 to the number else it stays the same. (I know how the bitwise operators act 'under the hood' but I thought there is a catch here.)

Comment: As explained in one answer, it's an bit rotation on the 8 lowest bits. So if your input has more than eight bits, the higher bits will be ignored, and the output will only be in the range 0-255 / `00000000` to `11111111`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seem that function is rotl - rotate left operation. So reverse would be rotr: rotate right:

```
def rotr(value):
    zbit = (value & 1) << 7
    return (value >> 1) | zbit
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot. Would you mind explaining how this works? what does it mean that function is rotate left operation?

Comment: I can recommend https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Rotate

Comment: I am not sure that I know how to explain such basic programming stuff in comment. Check Wikipedia link provided above. To understand what I have wrote, just take paper and implement all operations one by one manually. This function is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I created whole decryptor to this task (encryptor) - code you put is a part of it.
Check out:
https://github.com/sisidor69/CyWar_Decryptor

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).